# jquery quote rotator quovolver - is there a way to make the quotes random?

Tags: javascript, random

I finally got the wonderful "quovolver" to work on my site and my testimonials are all rotating in a lovely way in my sidebar...

I would like however that instead of them running in the same order all the time ( the script for quovolver cycles through them in the order they are in in the html... ) that they be called up randomly by the script...

Is this possible??

Here is the script:

```
/**
 * jQuery Quovolver 2.0.2
 * https://github.com/sebnitu/Quovolver
 *
 * By Sebastian Nitu - Copyright 2012 - All rights reserved
 * Author URL: http://sebnitu.com
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.quovolver = function(options) {

        // Extend our default options with those provided.
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.quovolver.defaults, options);

        // This allows for multiple instances of this plugin in the same document
        return this.each(function () {

            // Save our object
            var $this = $(this);

            // Build element specific options
            // This lets me access options with this syntax: o.optionName
            var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;

            // Initial styles and markup
            $this.addClass('quovolve')
                 .css({ 'position' : 'relative' })
                 .wrap('<div class="quovolve-box"></div>');

            if( o.children ) {
                var groupMethod = 'find';
            } else {
                var groupMethod = 'children';
            }

            // Initialize element specific variables
            var $box = $this.parent('.quovolve-box'),
                $items = $this[groupMethod](o.children),
                $active = 1,
                $total = $items.length;

            // Hide all except the first
            $items.hide().filter(':first').show();

            // Call build navigation function
            if ( o.navPrev || o.navNext || o.navNum || o.navText ) {
                o.navEnabled = true;
                var $nav = buildNav();
            } else {
                o.navEnabled = false;
            }

            // Call equal heights function
            if (o.equalHeight) {
                equalHeight( $items );
                // Recalculate equal heights on window resize
                $(window).resize(function() {
                    equalHeight( $items );
                    $this.css('height', $($items[$active -1]).outerHeight() );
                });
            }

            // Auto play interface
            if (o.autoPlay) {
                var $playID = autoPlay();
                if (o.stopOnHover) {
                    var $playID = stopAutoPlay($playID);
                } else if (o.pauseOnHover) {
                    var $playID = pauseAutoPlay($playID);
                }
            }

            // Go To function
            function gotoItem(itemNumber) {

                // Check if stuff is already being animated and kill the script if it is
                if( $items.is(':animated') || $this.is(':animated') ) return false;
                // If the container has been hidden, kill the script
                // This prevents the script from bugging out if something hides the revolving
                // object from another script (tabs for example)
                if( $box.is(':hidden') ) return false;

                // Don't let itemNumber go above or below possible options
                if ( itemNumber < 1 ) {
                    itemNumber = $total;
                } else if ( itemNumber > $total ) {
                    itemNumber = 1;
                }

                // Create the data object to pass to our transition method
                var gotoData = {
                        current : $( $items[$active -1] ), // Save currently active item
                        upcoming : $( $items[itemNumber - 1] ) // Save upcoming item
                }

                // Save current and upcoming hights and outer heights
                gotoData.currentHeight = getHiddenProperty(gotoData.current);
                gotoData.upcomingHeight = getHiddenProperty(gotoData.upcoming);
                gotoData.currentOuterHeight = getHiddenProperty(gotoData.current, 'outerHeight');
                gotoData.upcomingOuterHeight = getHiddenProperty(gotoData.upcoming, 'outerHeight');

                // Save current and upcoming widths and outer widths
                gotoData.currentWidth = getHiddenProperty(gotoData.current, 'width');
                gotoData.upcomingWidth = getHiddenProperty(gotoData.upcoming, 'width');
                gotoData.currentOuterWidth = getHiddenProperty(gotoData.current, 'outerWidth');
                gotoData.upcomingOuterWidth = getHiddenProperty(gotoData.upcoming, 'outerWidth');

                // Transition method
                if (o.transition != 'basic' &&
                    typeof o.transition == 'string' &&
                    eval('typeof ' + o.transition) == 'function' ) {
                    // Run the passed method
                    eval( o.transition + '(gotoData)' );
                } else {
                    // Default transition method
                    basic(gotoData);
                }

                // Update active item
                $active = itemNumber;

                // Update navigation
                updateNavNum($nav);
                updateNavText($nav);

                // Disable default behavior
                return false;
            }

            // Build navigation
            function buildNav() {
                // Check the position of the nav and insert container
                if ( o.navPosition === 'above' || o.navPosition === 'both' ) {
                    $box.prepend('<div class="quovolve-nav quovolve-nav-above"></div>');
                    var nav = $box.find('.quovolve-nav');
                } 
                if ( o.navPosition === 'below' || o.navPosition === 'both' ) {
                    $box.append('<div class="quovolve-nav quovolve-nav-below"></div>');
                    var nav = $box.find('.quovolve-nav');
                } 
                if ( o.navPosition === 'custom' ) {
                    if ( o.navPositionCustom !== '' && $( o.navPositionCustom ).length !== 0 ) {
                        $( o.navPositionCustom ).append('<div class="quovolve-nav quovolve-nav-custom"></div>');
                        var nav = $( o.navPositionCustom ).find('.quovolve-nav');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Error', 'That custom selector did not return an element.');
                    }
                }

                // Previous and next navigation
                if ( o.navPrev ) {
                    nav.append('<span class="nav-prev"><a href="#">' + o.navPrevText + '</a></span>');
                }
                if ( o.navNext ) {
                    nav.append('<span class="nav-next"><a href="#">' + o.navNextText + '</a></span>');
                }
                // Numbered navigation
                if ( o.navNum ) {
                    nav.append('<ol class="nav-numbers"></ol>');
                    for (var i = 1; i < ($total + 1); i++ ) {
                        nav
                            .find('.nav-numbers')
                            .append('<li><a href="#item-' + i + '">' + i + '</a></li>');
                    }
                    updateNavNum(nav);
                }
                // Navigation description
                if ( o.navText ) {
                    nav.append('<span class="nav-text"></span>');
                    updateNavText(nav);
                }

                return nav;
            }

            // Get height of a hidden element
            function getHiddenProperty(item, property) {
                // Default method
                if (!property) property = 'height';

                // Check if item was hidden
                if ( $(this).is(':hidden') ) {
                    // Reveal the hidden item but not to the user
                    item.show().css({'position':'absolute', 'visibility':'hidden', 'display':'block'});
                }

                // Get the requested property
                var value = item[property]();

                // Check if item was hidden
                if ( $(this).is(':hidden') ) {
                    // Return the originally hidden item to it's original state
                    item.hide().css({'position':'static', 'visibility':'visible', 'display':'none'});
                }
                // Return the height
                return value;
            }

            // Equal Column Heights
            function equalHeight(group) {
                var tallest = 0;
                group.height('auto');
                group.each(function() {
                    if ( $(this).is(':visible') ) {
                        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
                    } else {
                        var thisHeight = getHiddenProperty( $(this) );
                    }
                    if(thisHeight > tallest) {
                        tallest = thisHeight;
                    }
                });
                group.height(tallest);
            }

            // Update numbered navigation
            function updateNavNum(nav) {
                if (o.navEnabled) {
                    nav.find('.nav-numbers li').removeClass('active');
                    nav
                        .find('.nav-numbers a[href="#item-' + $active + '"]')
                        .parent()
                        .addClass('active');
                }
            }

            // Update navigation description
            function updateNavText(nav) {
                if (o.navEnabled) {
                    var content = o.navTextContent.replace('@a', $active).replace('@b', $total);
                    nav.find('.nav-text').text(content);
                }
            }

            // Start auto play
            function autoPlay() {
                $box.addClass('play');
                intervalID = setInterval(function() {
                    gotoItem( $active + 1 );
                }, o.autoPlaySpeed);
                return intervalID;
            }

            // Pause auto play
            function pauseAutoPlay(intervalID) {
                if ( o.stopAutoPlay !== true ) {
                    $box.hover(function() {
                        $box.addClass('pause').removeClass('play');
                        clearInterval(intervalID);
                    }, function() {
                        $box.removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
                        clearInterval(intervalID);
                        intervalID = autoPlay();
                    });
                    return intervalID;
                }
            }

            // Stop auto play
            function stopAutoPlay(intervalID) {
                $box.hover(function() {
                    $box.addClass('stop').removeClass('play');
                    clearInterval(intervalID);
                }, function() {});
                return intervalID;
            }

            // Transition Effects
            // Basic (default) Just swaps out items with no animation
            function basic(data) {
                $this.css('height', data.upcomingOuterHeight);
                data.current.hide();
                data.upcoming.show();
                if (o.equalHeight === false) {
                    $this.css('height', 'auto');
                }
            }

            // Fade animation
            function fade(data) {

                // Set container to current item's height
                $this.height(data.currentOuterHeight);

                // Fade out the current container
                data.current.fadeOut(o.transitionSpeed, function() {
                    // Resize container to upcming item's height
                    $this.animate({
                        height : data.upcomingOuterHeight
                    }, o.transitionSpeed, function() {
                        // Fade in the upcoming item
                        data.upcoming.fadeIn(o.transitionSpeed, function() {
                            // Set height of container to auto
                            $this.height('auto');
                        });
                    });
                });

            }

            // Bind to the forward and back buttons
            $('.nav-prev a').click(function () {
                return gotoItem( $active - 1 );
            });
            $('.nav-next a').click(function () {
                return gotoItem( $active + 1 );
            });

            // Bind the numbered navigation buttons
            $('.nav-numbers a').click(function() {
                return gotoItem( $(this).text() );
            });

            // Create a public interface to move to a specific item
            $(this).bind('goto', function (event, item) {
                gotoItem( item );
            });

        }); // @end of return this.each()

    };

    $.fn.quovolver.defaults = {

        children : '', // If selector is provided, we will use the find method to get the group of items

        transition : 'fade', // The style of the transition
        transitionSpeed : 300, // This is the speed that each animation will take, not the entire transition

        autoPlay : true, // Toggle auto rotate
        autoPlaySpeed : 6000, // Duration before each transition
        pauseOnHover : true, // Should the auto rotate pause on hover
        stopOnHover : false, // Should the auto rotate stop on hover (and not continue after hover)
        equalHeight : true, // Should every item have equal heights

        navPosition : 'above', // above, below, both, custom (must provide custom selector for placement)
        navPositionCustom : '', // selector of custom element

        navPrev : false, // Toggle "previous" button
        navNext : false, // Toggle "next" button
        navNum : false, // Toggle numbered navigation
        navText : false, // Toggle navigation description (e.g. display current item # and total item #)

        navPrevText : 'Prev', // Text for the "previous" button
        navNextText : 'Next', // Text for the "next" button
        navTextContent : '@a / @b' // @a will be replaced with current and @b with total

    };
})(jQuery);
```

and here is a very simple example of the html that works with it...

```
<div class="quovolver">

<div>1</div>

<div>2</div>

<div>3</div>

<div>4</div>

</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately there seems to be no built-in function to handle random items and looking at the `gotoItem` function briefly it's quite hardcoded to use sequential items, what you could perhaps do, is load the items randomly at page load and thus this plugin could stay as is.

Comment: thank you @f0x, i understand what you are saying, how would i go about loading the items randomly at page load as you say?

Comment: can you show me how you do it currently and perhaps I can help you.

Comment: i would be happy to, but i am not sure how to show you? what exactly do you need me to copy paste here?

Comment: Oh perhaps I understood incorrectly, are those quotes just static html? not populated on page load?

Comment: i think it is static? it is html which I have put in a text widget in the sidebar on my wordpress site...

Comment: Ok ;) give me a few minutes and I'll see if I can put something together.

Comment: how nice of you, thank you so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took a bit longer than anticipated ;)

Let me know if this works for you.

You can replace your current Quovolver code with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $items = $('.quovolver .quote');
    var quovolver = $('.quovolver');
    var newItems = [];

    $.each($items, function(i, quote) {
        var $copy = $(quote);
        newItems.push($copy);
        $copy.remove();
    });

    var random;
    var chosenRandom = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length - 1; i++) {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * newItems.length);
        while ($.inArray(random, chosenRandom) != -1) {
            random = Math.floor(Math.random() * newItems.length);
        }
        chosenRandom.push(random);
        quovolver.append(newItems[random]);
    }
    $('div.quovolver').quovolver({autoPlaySpeed : 6000});
});​
```

***EDIT***

To fix the overlapping divs, I have made a small adjustment in the code above, besides that, can you change the CSS Class `testimonial_widget` to include : `overflow:hidden`  ? That will also aid in hiding the divs that are creeping over it.

Secondly the length of each div can be changed in the script above, when passing an object to quovolver, modify the following:

`autoPlaySpeed : 6000` to however many (seconds * 1000) that you want it to wait.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: that is really great f0x! It is working, appears to be totally random, just a couple of things... 1. when the page first loads, i can see all the divs for a second or so, they overlap other divs etc... is there a way to fix this? 2. how would i make each div "last longer" on the page? ( give people more time to read each one)... thank you so much for your help, i really appreciate it...

Comment: @Xenia - just a second, let me have a look

Comment: thank you so much! that is working now, no overlapping of text etc, I will play around with the speed of transition plus the autoPlaySpeed until i am happy with it... I can't thank you enough, do you accept donations or something like that? thank you...